# Unable to understand asynchronous functions in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I have spent 6 hours already trying to figure out how to do this in NodeJS.

I am using NodeJS with Express and MongoDB.

I have a database that has two collections viz. Listings and Categories. Each listing has a "category" which is an ID that maps to a category inside the Categories collection.

What I want to do is, fetch all the listings, then loop through all of them, and get the category title from the Categories collection using the category id.

This is what I had for getting all the listings:

```
const listings_raw = [];

await db.collection("listings").find().forEach(listing => listings_raw.push(listing));
```

The code above works fine. The trouble I am having is with this:

```
const listings = [];

listings_raw.forEach(async listing => {
    const category_id = listing.category;

    const category_title = await db.collection('categories').findOne({_id: objectId(category_id)});

    listing.category_title = category_title;

    listings.push(listing);
});

response.send(listings);
```

The `response.send(listings);` gets executed before the `listings_raw.forEach` completes.

I want to send the data only after all listings have been populated with the category titles.

After spending 6 hours, I have come up with the following hack which I am sure is nasty!

```
const listings_raw = [];

const em = new events.EventEmitter();

await db.collection("listings").find().forEach(listing => listings_raw.push(listing));

const listings = [];

let counter = 0;

listings_raw.forEach(async (listing) => {
    const category_id = listing.category;

    const category = await db.collection('categories').findOne({_id: objectId(category_id)});

    listing.category_title = category.title;

    listings.push(listing);

    if (counter === listings_raw.length - 1) {
        em.emit('listings:processing:done');
    }

    counter++;
});

em.on('listings:processing:done', () => {
    response.send(listings);
});
```

Please, can someone explain or guide me on how this should be done in JavaScript?

Basically, I am not able to figure out how to know if all promises have been resolved or not.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listings_raw.forEach` function executes synchronously on the array, even though you are then performing an asynchronous operation within that.

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will allow you to `await` for the result of an array of promises. Therefore you can `.map` the listings to an array of promises *which* return the updated listing.

```js
const listings = await Promise.all(listings_raw.map(async listing => {
    const category_id = listing.category;

    const category_title = await db.collection('categories').findOne({_id: dependencies.objectId(category_id)});

    listing.category_title = category_title;

    return listing;
});

response.send(listings);
```

Comment: WOW! You nailed it in what, 1 minute? Do you know what I should be reading more about to be able to understand this very well? My only experience has been with languages like PHP.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make until you've nailed how async JS works. MDN has some excellent resources - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: Having a strong understanding of callbacks and promises helps a lot. async-await just makes it look nicer.